# AngularJS Template not properly loading

Tags: angularjs

Had a bit of trouble with Angular earlier, but I was able to resolve that problem. Of course, being a newbie, we've hit more problems!

Did some searching around for this error, but applying the fixes that other people have tried has not proven effective for me.

I am currently trying to load a partial onto a show page in Rails using AngularJS.
EDIT: I apologize- I forgot to mention that I intend to load a partial from a file in the same directory as all these files. Current directory tree is as follows:

[Directory containing relevant js files and the timer partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epHRe.png)

I have the following code built out:

**Show.html.erb**

```
<timer-info ng-controller = "CountdownController">

</timer-info>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module("summoners-universe", ['ngRoute'])
```

**directives.js**

```
'use strict';

myApp.directive("timerInfo", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: 'app/assets/javascripts/timer.html'
  };
});
```

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';

myApp.controller('CountdownController', 
  ["$scope", "$http", "$routeParams", 
  function($scope, $http, $routeParams){
  console.log($routeParams);
}]);
```

Eventually this controller will display a countdown timer, but for now, I just wanted to make sure I could get my routeParams and all that.

Sadly, I'm hit with the following error upon page load:

```
angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11757 GET http://localhost:3000/games/app/assets/javascripts/timer.html 404 (Not Found)(anonymous function) @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11757sendReq @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11518serverRequest @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11228processQueue @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:15962(anonymous function) @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:15978Scope.$eval @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17230Scope.$digest @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17046Scope.$apply @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17338bootstrapApply @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:1750invoke @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:4666doBootstrap @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:1748bootstrap @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:1768angularInit @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:1653(anonymous function) @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:30864fire @ jquery.self-4e23968….js?body=1:3188self.fireWith @ jquery.self-4e23968….js?body=1:3318jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.self-4e23968….js?body=1:3537completed @ jquery.self-4e23968….js?body=1:3553
angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:13551 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: app/assets/javascripts/timer.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$compile/tpload?p0=app%2Fassets%2Fjavascripts%2Ftimer.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
    at angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:69
    at handleError (angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:18979)
    at processQueue (angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:15962)
    at angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:15978
    at Scope.$eval (angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17230)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17046)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17338)
    at done (angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11573)
    at completeRequest (angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11779)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11712)(anonymous function) @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:13551(anonymous function) @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:10226processQueue @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:15970(anonymous function) @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:15978Scope.$eval @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17230Scope.$digest @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17046Scope.$apply @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17338done @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11573completeRequest @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11779requestLoaded @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11712XMLHttpRequest.send (async)(anonymous function) @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11757sendReq @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11518serverRequest @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:11228processQueue @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:15962(anonymous function) @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:15978Scope.$eval @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17230Scope.$digest @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17046Scope.$apply @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:17338bootstrapApply @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:1750invoke @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:4666doBootstrap @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:1748bootstrap @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:1768angularInit @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:1653(anonymous function) @ angular.self-208d6d1….js?body=1:30864fire @ jquery.self-4e23968….js?body=1:3188self.fireWith @ jquery.self-4e23968….js?body=1:3318jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.self-4e23968….js?body=1:3537completed @ jquery.self-4e23968….js?body=1:3553
```

I don't know why a get request is being made to that URL. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Fires from your directive `timerInfo`.

Comment: So, how do I get the templateUrl to render the timer.html file that is in the same directory as my directives file? I'll update my OP with proper info.

Comment: In templateUrl, the url with "/" prefix is relative to the domain, without the "/" prefix it will be relative to the main ("index.html") page or base url (if you use location in the html5 mode). So, it depends your where is your index.html, if without html5mode.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. What changes should I be looking to make?

Comment: Need to know your directory tree that contains index.html and your directive..., or I cant figure out either.

Comment: @YinGang I added that as a link to the screenshot of the directory containing all of the relevant files to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The templateUrl of the `timerInfo` should be absolute, like this:

`templateUrl: '/app/assets/javascripts/timer.html'`

This way you're referencing from the root directory down to the desired file.

Comment: No dice. Error just now reads as: http://localhost:3000/app/assets/javascripts/timer.html Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I was able to figure it out. Apparently, the Angular-Rails gem looks for templates to load in an app/templates directory. I just had to make that directory and put the template there.